# Master Theorem Help - How to make the value of "b" greater than 1 as required by the Master Theorem? What math is involved?

Tags: master-theorem

I know how to identify the parts of the Master Theorem, and I know that it is a recurrence relation. I don't understand how to make the "b" value greater than 1.

Please see the image. I know the math is easy, but I am not seeing it. Can someone help?
[image]

Comment: I found the answer. It is very easy, lol. I can't believe I didn't see it. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)).